# Error when modifying list in python

Tags: python, list

I have had a problem when trying to change a specific item that is in a nested list.The code I have written is in python 2.7.
This is what i have written:

```
list_1 = []
list_2 = []
infin = 25
while infin != 0:
    list_1.append((0,0,0))
    infin = infin - 1
infin = 5
while infin != 0:
    list_2.append(list_1)
    infin = infin - 1
```

Basically it makes a list that looks like this:

> [[*25 tuples*],[*25 tuples*],[*25 tuples*],[*25 tuples*],[*25 tuples*]]

then when i attempt to modify the list by doing this:

```
list_2[0][0] = (1,1,1)
```

Every single list with 25 tuples in it will have (1,1,1) at the start, not just the first. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are appending the same list `list_1` 5 times. What you change in list_1 is printed 5 times, because the list has been added 5 times.
If you want new lists, use:

```
list(list_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually appending different instances of lists, instead you're repeatedly appending a reference to the same list.  Use list to avoid this.

```
list_1 = []
list_2 = []
infin = 25
while infin != 0:
    list_1.append((0,0,0))
    infin = infin - 1
infin = 5
while infin != 0:
    list_2.append(list(list_1))
    infin = infin - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`list_1` is a object.  You then add the object to another list 5 times, creating not 5 copies of the object, but 5 references to the same object.

You need to copy the list as you create the second list:

```
infin = 5
while infin != 0:
    list_2.append(list(list_1))
    infin = infin - 1
```